# didSelectRowAt no longer working after tvOS 17 Update

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tvos

after the recent tvOS17 update, didSelectRowAt is no longer working for my table view. I'm very confused as to what is going on and I am in desperate need of assistance.

Here's a checklist of things I've tried.

1. table_view.dataSource = self
2. table_view.delegate = self
3. table_view.allowsSelection = true
4. UITapGestureRecognizers that are used have cancelsTouchesInView set to false (I did further testing by removing them altogether to no avail).
5. User Interaction Enabled - for both the table, the cells, and the contents within.
6. Tried commenting out pressesBegan for both the table and cells (didn't work so uncommented them back).

Anytime I try selecting a table cell, didSelectRowAt will not be invoked and focus would just move focus elsewhere.

**Here is the table view code (much omitted)**

```
@IBDesignable
class channel_list_view: UIView, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, slice_view_event_receiver, channel_list_table_cell_event_receiver {
    @IBOutlet weak var channel_list_table_view: UITableView!
    var view: UIView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        common_init()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        common_init()
    }

    func common_init() {
        view = load_view_from_nib()
        view.frame = bounds
        addSubview(view)
    
        channel_list_table_view.allowsSelection = true
        

        channel_list_table_view.register(UINib(nibName: "channel_list_table_cell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "channel_list_table_cell")
                 

        channel_list_table_view.dataSource = self
        channel_list_table_view.delegate = self
        
        channel_list_table_view.remembersLastFocusedIndexPath = true

        let left_swipe_recogniser = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swipe_gesture_occurred))
        left_swipe_recogniser.direction = .left
        view.addGestureRecognizer(left_swipe_recogniser)
    }
  
    override func pressesBegan(_ presses: Set<UIPress>, with event: UIPressesEvent?) {
        // Code here gets called
        for press in presses {
            if press.type == .leftArrow {
                event_receiver?.leave_channel_list(selected_guide_item: nil)
                return
            }
        }
        
        super.pressesBegan(presses, with: event)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // NOT WORKING - Code here isn't getting called
    }
}
```

**Here is the table cell code (much omitted)**

```
@IBDesignable
class channel_list_table_cell: UITableViewCell  {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code

        layer.cornerRadius = ui_constants.corner_radius     

        listen_for_gestures()
    }

    func listen_for_gestures() {
        let swipe_recogniser = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swipe_gesture_occurred))
        swipe_recogniser.direction = .right
        self.addGestureRecognizer(swipe_recogniser)
    }

    override func pressesBegan(_ presses: Set<UIPress>, with event: UIPressesEvent?) {
        for press in presses {
            if press.type == .rightArrow {
                event_receiver?.slice_open(cell: self)
                return
            }
        }
        
        super.pressesBegan(presses, with: event)
    }

    func ignore_gestures() {
        gestureRecognizers?.removeAll()
    }

    @objc func swipe_gesture_occurred(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {
            switch swipeGesture.direction {
            case .right:
                event_receiver?.slice_open(cell: self)
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**The table cell contains this view code within it (in case it is relevant):**

```
@IBDesignable
class channel_view: UIView {
    @IBOutlet weak var programme_image: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var channel_image: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var programme_title: marquee_view!
    @IBOutlet weak var channel_name: marquee_view!
    @IBOutlet weak var channel_number: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var progress: progress_line_view!
    @IBOutlet weak var slice_arrow: UILabel!

    // A bunch of setters and getters...
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        common_init()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        common_init()
    }

    func common_init() {
        view = load_view_from_nib()
        view.frame = bounds
        addSubview(view)
                
        programme_title.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(hex: UInt32(0x324a6eff))
        programme_title.font_colour = UIColor.white

        channel_name.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(hex: UInt32(0x00000000))
        channel_name.font_colour = UIColor.white
        
        channel_number.textColor = UIColor.white

    }
}
```

I would appreciate any assistance. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am also having this issue, did you manage the cause of it or find a workaround?